# Bug: Text Not Lining Up With Images

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've gotten this several times now but after a while the issue would disappear and I thought maybe it was just my imagination or something. But then the bug would appear again.

Somehow the text and image would not line up for the badges and the privileges. Take a look at the image below:

[image]

The text seems to skew lower than what it is suppose to correspond to. And if I'm not mistaken part of the badge image seem to be cut off.

Note: I am using Windows 7 with IE8. I will test it on Firefox and Chrome later.

Comment: This is what it looks like in IE7, so my bet is that your browser switched itself to compatibility mode. If I have to guess, it's related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114602/pressing-the-enter-key-to-complete-a-comment-switches-internet-explorer-8-to-com -- I wish I could reproduce that stupid issue :\

Comment: @balpha You're right, it only happens when it switches to compatibility mode.